# How to number a grid fabrics

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

This is a beginner javascript/fabric.js "for/Loop"question. I'm using fabric.js. I have searched stack overflow, w3schools, googled , and looked in books, but I can't really find an answer that makes sense to me or applies directly to what I am trying to do.

I have two functions. One function turns on a grid view in the fabric.js canvas. One turns it off. The code is based on [create a snap to grid using fabricjs](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/S9sLu/).I use two buttons that are contained in a div element above the canvas to turn the grid off and on.

I would like to automatically number the grid lines both horizontally and vertically by an increment of 5 (0, 5,10,15,20...)
0   ......5.......10.......15.......20
    .    .
5   .    .
    .    .
10  .    .
    .    .
15  .    .
    .    .
20  .    .

As it stands now, I'm trying to use a for loop with spaces, but I know this is terrible coding. I'm just learning. The numbers don't line up using spaces (. How does one do this with code?
[image: Grid]

```
 <div id="demo"><script>
    var count;
                for(count = 0; count < 10; count++){
                   document.write(count + "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp;&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp;&nbsp &nbsp");
                }

    </script></div>
```

Comment: It looks like the example code you posted has `var grid = 50` which defines the pixel dimensions of a cell in the grid. So `50px` is the space you need between the numbers. 

Instead of using raw text `&nbsp`, use an html element like a span for each number, and apply an inline style to position it based on the `count*grid`

Comment: @miir Would you add a little code to go with your comment? I'm not sure how to set this up. I've tried and failed.

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't that helpful. No Grabbing 's answer is better than the approach I was suggesting. Let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: @mir I appreciate everyone's contribution. I like to see alternative approaches since I'm always trying to learn. No Grabbing's answer is totally awesome for the time she put in answering be clearly so that I could understand, but her answer shows the solution within the canvas. I'm curious how this is done outside of the canvas too. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1204493 – updated my answer with better code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not what you are looking for but I wanted to play with `FabricJS`.

This fiddle draws the text on the canvas: http://jsfiddle.net/sunny001/ctdcp8j0/47/ I couldn't get the text in the vertical column to align right for some reason. The code is just a hack but maybe it suggests an approach.

---

**Update:** We had a snow day here and I want to understand `Fabric.js` better so I played around with making a grid function. It could be much more compact and concise. Still couldn't get the vertical column of text to right align. Everything is contained in a group so toggling visibility/z-order is easy.

Assumes that there is a `Fabric.js` instance called `canvas`

```
drawGrid(50, 600, 400, 100, 100);
```

[image]

```
function drawGrid(cellSize, gridWidth, gridHeight, xPos, yPos) {

    var bkgndrect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: gridWidth + 50,
        height: gridHeight + 50,
        stroke: '#ccc',
        fill: 'transparent',
        selectable: false
    });

    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 25,
        top: 25,
        width: gridWidth,
        height: gridHeight,
        stroke: '#000000',
        fill: '#cccccc',
        selectable: false
    });

    var gridGroup = new fabric.Group([bkgndrect, rect], {
        left: xPos,
        top: yPos,
        selectable: false
    });

    canvas.add(gridGroup);

    for (var i = 1; i < (gridWidth / cellSize); i++) {
        var line = new fabric.Line([0, 0, 0, gridHeight], {
            left: (gridWidth / 2) - i * cellSize,
            top: -gridHeight / 2,
            stroke: '#000000',
            selectable: false
        });
        gridGroup.add(line);
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < (gridHeight / cellSize); i++) {
        var line = new fabric.Line([0, 0, gridWidth, 0], {
            left: -gridWidth / 2,
            top: (gridHeight / 2) - i * cellSize,
            stroke: '#000000',
            selectable: false
        });
        gridGroup.add(line);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < (gridWidth / cellSize); i++) {
        var text = new fabric.Text(String((i) * 5), {
            left: -(gridWidth / 2) + i * cellSize,
            top: -(gridHeight / 2) - 20,
            fontSize: 14,
            selectable: false
        });
        gridGroup.add(text);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < (gridHeight / cellSize); i++) {
        var text = new fabric.Text(String((i) * 5), {
            left: -(gridWidth / 2) - 20,
            top: -(gridHeight / 2) + (i) * cellSize,
            fontSize: 14,
            textAlign: 'right',
            selectable: false
        });
        gridGroup.add(text);
    }

    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Comment: @ No Grabbing. Thank you for this contribution! I'm going to see if I can get it to work for my purposes. I'm also fighting with how to make the grid go to the background. When I turn the grid on with a button click, it's z index goes to the top of the stack and overlays all of the objects on the canvas. Thanks again, I really appreciate your help. -Rachel

Comment: use inset-7 to fix the alignment

Comment: @miir – "inset-7"? Is that a property of a Fabrijs object? Please elaborate.

Comment: @No-Grabbing My fault, I meant inset as its used on line 18 ```{left: inset + i * grid, top: 0, ``` and line 23 ```{left:0, top: inset + i * grid,``` ...You mentioned that you couldn't get the vertical column of text to align.  I tried moving it by 7 pixels to align it: ```inset + i*grid``` --> ```inset-7+i*grid```. maybe I misunderstood your alignment issue.

Comment: @miir – yeah, I'm wondering why the "textAlign: 'right'" doesn't work. Haven't had time to check the Fabric github issues to see if it is a "known" issue.

Comment: @No-Grabbing I apologize for being so dense, but where do I place this: drawGrid(50, 600, 400, 100, 100);? I've tried putting it both as a script in the canvas element and at the top of your script. Nothing works. I just see a blank canvas. I am not a good programmer, but I do try. In days gone by, we got to draw our interfaces. That is what led me to programming since, now, it is all about coding. -Rachel

Comment: @user1204493 – no problem. I'm coming from Flex/Actionscript and though I have a lot of programming experience, this JS/HTML/CSS stuff is still pretty confusing. I made a fiddle with a bunch of comments: https://jsfiddle.net/sunny001/2ber0fgd/6/

Comment: @No-Grabbing- Got side tracked with another app. I am accepting your kind answer. I think I can get it working when I get some more time to work on it. You went above and beyond what most people do on stack overflow. I thank you and appreciate your effort. -Rachel